# Need to disable/re-enable wifi for wifi to work again after 30 minutes

Tags: windows-10

I am this weekend at my parents' house and I'm losing wifi internet on my Macbook every 20 minutes, I have to turn off the Wi-Fi connection and back on again. My father wants to buy a new laptop, because he has the same problem on his Sony Vaio laptop.

The tablet of my mother and my brother's laptop don't have the problem, which is weird.

Any idea how I can troubleshoot?

Comment: Please, tell your WI-Fi router model and also tell your mother's tablet and your brother's laptop model. What's your macbook model exactly?

Comment: Mother's tablet: Nexus 10, (sorry, didn't mean to enter, collecting other info)

Comment: Nexus 10 has no issues. My MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015) has issues every 30 minutes. Sony Vaio with C605PEK9 as Service Tag has issues. Mobile devices and my brother's Dell laptop work fine.

Comment: It's a Cisco EPC 3925 Ziggo router.

Comment: Did you upgrade your router firmware?

Comment: According to your router user manual, `When TKIP authentication only is selected, B/G/N Mixed network mode is not available`. So please check this option and be sure that this option configure on `B/G/N`.